# htaccess (RewriteRule) works in wamp but in the real server doesn't

Tags: apache, .htaccess

The following htaccess works fine in wamp server, but when I upload the file into the real server it doesn’t work and I don’t know why.

```
RewriteEngine on
Options -Indexes +FollowSymlinks
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^groups/(.+)$ groups.php?url_in=$1
```

groups.php doesn’t receive any $_GET parameter. If I type var_dump($_GET); at the top of groups.php and try to go to www.mydomain.com/groups/mygroup, it shows:

```
array(0) { }
```

I appreciate any help. Sorry if I made mistakes writing in English, it's not my first language.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try turning off multiviews by adding a `-Multiviews` to your options:

```
Options -Indexes +FollowSymlinks -Multiviews
```

Comment: Wow! It works perfectly. I'd like to vote up but I have not enought reputation. Thanks a lot!!